# How can I get full content of a git repository with all branches?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I read [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) this text:

> If you want to get a copy of an existing Git repository – for example, a project you’d like to contribute to – the command you need is `git clone`.

I need to get **complete** repository (with all branches).

But when I use the command `git clone <address> <output_directory_name>` then I get clone with one branch only. I see it through the `git branch` command. If I use the `git clone <address> -b <branch_name> <output_directory_name>` then I get only that branch (I see it through the `git branch` command again).

How can I get **full** content of a git repository with all branches? The repositories which I cloned are located on Bitbucket website.

Answer (score 1):

A regular `git clone ...` followed by a `git fetch --all` will do the trick.

Comment: I did `git fetch --all` after cloning, but I see one branch still.

Comment: Try `git branch --list`.